# JavaScript Array By Index

Tags: javascript

Sure it's a stupid mistake but can't see what I'm doing wrong here but when I test in my fiddle I can't get a result, could someone point out where I'm going wrong please?

In the code below and in the fiddle I'm trying to return the value for array id: 15.

https://jsfiddle.net/wc71ra6r/3/

**Code**

```
function findValueById(myA, fVal) {
    for(var i = 0; i < myA.length; i++){
        if(myA[i].id === fVal) {
            return myA[i].value;
        }
    }
}

var myArray = [{id: 10, value: 100},
               {id: 15, value: 300},
               {id: 20, value: 200];

alert(findValueById(myArray, 15)); // 300
```

Comment: You need to close the bracket for the last object in the array.

Comment: Add `}` to the last element in array. https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wc71ra6r/4/

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close your array deceleration right:
Replace your array declaration with this:

```
var myArray = [{id: 10, value: 100},
               {id: 15, value: 300},
               {id: 20, value: 200}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [{id: 10, value: 100},
               {id: 15, value: 300},
               {id: 20, value: 200}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `}` in array

```
var myArray = [{id: 10, value: 100},
               {id: 15, value: 300},
               {id: 20, value: 200}];
```